# Unable to test facebook messenger bot. Webhook not receiving events

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-webhooks

Following the recent changes for facebook developer, i had this alert on the webhook section on the developer dashboard, and therefore no webhook messages are received from 'testers, devs, etc' ;

[image: Application will only be able to receive test webhooks sent from ...]

As a result i am unable to test my mesenger bot apps. 
I have created "Test users" from the "roles" section;

[image]

When i login with any "Test Users", the messenger bot app created does not appear in the Messenger Bot search.

Kindly note that my initial Webhook subscription at the developer dashboard is successful.

I want to test the bot before submitting for approval, is my approach wrong?
I am really at a loss as how to proceed. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is in development mode, your bot will still be able to send messages to users with the developer, tester, or administrator role for the app.

Comment: Hmm, app is in development mode, but still no response at the node backend. The webhook route test is always called though.

Comment: Does the user messaging your app have one of the roles I listed?

Comment: It works, ignore my earlier comment. I neglected to add a post route after the development mode activation. Tnx @amuramoto

Comment: @amuramoto Hi, i'm having the same issue with messenger BOT, i'm using PHP, but (file_get_contents("php://input")) returns empty string. I saw the same  alert on my dashboard, i am an administrator on the page and on the app. Any idea what i can do to test the app?